# My function doesn't not return object in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I created a function which takes the inner of the tag `S` in a XML string:

```
'<C><P /><Z><S>[Grounds here]</S><D /><O /></Z></C>'
```

, containing grounds data, obviously related to a game. Then I consume every ground data in this inner until I reach the number `z` with `i` in my `for` loop and return the data of the first/one remaining ground as a object.

The problem: the function returns `undefined` instead of a `object`.

---

This is the function:

```
/**
 * Get a string between 2 strings.
 */
String.prototype.between = function(left, right) {
    var sub = this.substr(this.lastIndexOf(left) + left.length);
    return sub.substr(0, sub.indexOf(right));
}

/**
 * @param {Number} z The inner position of the ground I want to read, e.g, 1, the first.
 */
function readGround(z) {

     // string containing all existent grounds
    var groundsData = xml.substr(STG.indexOf('<S>') + 3, STG.lastIndexOf('</S>'));

     // Iterate the grounds while z isn't reached
    for(var i = 1; i < z; i++) {

        // Get the ground inner
        var outer = groundsData.substr(groundsData.indexOf('<S') + 3, groundsData.indexOf('/>'));

        // Check if i reached z
        if(i === z) {

            // Get grounds properties
            var a = [
                outer.between('L="', '"'),
                outer.between('H="', '"'),
                outer.between('X="', '"'),
                outer.between('Y="', '"')
            ];

            return {
                L: a[0], H: a[1],
                X: a[2], Y: a[3]
            };

        // Else skip this ground
        } else groundsData = groundsData.substr(groundsData.indexOf('/>'), groundsData.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you put everything in one line? That's pretty much unreadable...

Comment: Thanks for editing, sometimes I prefer keep one line.

Comment: Can you add a real sample of what STG might contain?

Comment: I forgot to add it in code. It contain the XML of actual map.

Comment: Your loop stops before `i == NUM`, so the condition `i == NUM` is never fulfilled and it never returns anything.

Comment: But this stops the loop after return value, then I think that's not a problem.

Comment: I guess that's impossible... may be a fail of Javascript language. :( Sorry. I already tried almost all that I can and did much tests. I can say there's no solution. Thanks for help of you all.

Comment: Yeah, "return from function inside a loop" is totally impossible and a fail of JS... >_>

Comment: I just should not do that again. Thanks.

Comment: @ThiefMaster The truth is that I used to make unreadable codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop makes `i` go from `1` to `num-1`. But within the loop you have a condition `if(i==num)`. This condition is never true, so the programme never reaches the `return` statement. If the programme flow inside a function means that no `return` statement is ever reached, then the function simply returns `undefined`. (This isn't javascript-specific - similar rules apply in many languages.)

Instead, you can move the `return` statement *outside* of the loop.

```
function readGround(num) {
    var grounds = stg.substr(stg.indexOf('<S>') + 3, stg.lastIndexOf('</S>')),
        gr;
    for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        grounds = grounds.substr(grounds.indexOf('/>') + 2, grounds.length);
    }
    gr = grounds.substr(grounds.indexOf('<S') + 3, grounds.indexOf('/>'));
    var a = [stringBetween(gr, 'L="', '"'), stringBetween(gr, 'H="', '"'), stringBetween(gr, 'X="', '"'), stringBetween(gr, 'Y="', '"')];
    return {
        L: a[0],
        H: a[1],
        X: a[2],
        Y: a[3]
    };
}
```

(A few other things also had to be tweaked to make your code work, such as that `a` should read from the section of text in `gr` rather than from the longer string `grounds`)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fkde1zv/1)